# Prove np-hard with reduction from scheduling resources

Tags: algorithms

Lets say I have a set of destinations and another corresponding set of origins. I need to link each destination with one origin.A set of vehicles start from each origin towards their respective destination.The speed of every vehicle is provided.

In the network no two vehicles moving in opposite directions are allowed to move on a particular road at any instance of time,in brief there should not be any collisions on a road,if such a situation arrives,any one of the two vehicles which can collide on the road can wait till the other vehicle is passed or take some another path to reach its destination.In any situation no two vehicles can travel in opposite direction on the same road.

The graph can be thought of a road network where each edge in the graph represents the road and vertices in the graph can be thought of intersection of the edges.

The aim is to calculate the minimum time required for the last vehicle to reach its destination and also the path taken by each vehicle to reach its destination satisfying all the above constraints.

Now lets consider the segments of the road as resources ,that is a particular segment which joins two junction and the given set of origins and destination as process.Now i know that is NP-HARD,but i want to reduce this from some resource scheduling problem which is also NP-HARD.

The problem can be thought as a real life problem,so the size of the network can be very large comprising more than 100 vertices and more than 400 edges

Is there any np-hard scheduling problem which can be reduced to this problem in polynomial time?

Comment: i have edited the question and also waiting here means the vehicle will wait at a junction(vertex) until the vehicle moving  on the road(in opposite direction) on which former vehicle is supposed to travel has finished travelling on that particular road.There can not be pull over and in any case no two cars can travel on the same road travelling in opposite directions.